# hereinafter or abbreviate

Tags: word-choice, abbreviations

In my document if I mention the first time "File 1234 (in the Official Records hereinafter)", then after that in the same document if I say "File 5678", will that mean that "File 6789 of the Official Records" too? Or how could I do this?

Comment: You could use an early sentence announcing that all files you refer to are from the Official Records. The word *hereinafter* is old-fashioned.

Comment: Why would "File 5678" refer to File 6789?

Answer (score 3):

As Yosef notes in a comment, *hereinafter* is very old-fashioned: you'll only ever find it used today in formal legal documents like leases and statutes.

I would say

> ... File 1234 (All files cited are from the  Official Records unless otherwise indicated) ...

If there are no exceptions you can omit *unless otherwise indicated*.